# urlopen failure in python but successful in R

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, urlopen

I am trying to download a dataset from a web API for my work project which requires using python. I used python 3.4 and the library urllib to open the request. This does not work:

```
from urllib import request
r = request.urlopen(SOME_URL)
```

This gives error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
   return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 463, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 481, in _open
   '_open', req)
   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
   result = func(*args)
   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1210, in http_open
   return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1184, in do_open
   raise URLError(err)
   urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection  attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a   period of time,
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

But when I used RStudio with the same URL, it works:

```
dt = read.csv(SOME_URL)
```

This gives me the exact dataset I want.

For the project we want to keep a unified tech stack (only use python throughout the process), does anyone have idea why the URL can be open in R but not python? Is there any special set-up I need to configure for python?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide examples of how you've formatted the url string in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job:

```
urllib2.urlopen(SOME_URL).read()
```